# How to position elements within views?

Tags: views, media, theming

I have a view which is displaying a content type with text and image (1 column grid). Right now, the image is positioned under the text. Is it possible to position the image to the right?

Is this possible without using custom css? Or if it isn't, which css file should i be looking for? (Haven't done custom css yet)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish a floating image is to have some custom css: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/

Anyway, the drupal module Media can help you alot. Please follow this complete and well explained article: http://purewebmedia.biz/articles/2013-01-10/how-insert-and-float-inline-images-drupal-7.